# Is a mutex defined statically in a function body able to lock properly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, static-variables

Is a mutex defined statically in a function body able to lock properly? I am currently using this pattern in my logger system, but I have not tested it's thread safety yet.

```
void foo () {
    static std::mutex mu;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mu);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NathanOliver's answer is not accurate: `mu` is actually *statically* initialized – this means before any dynamic initialization, and therefore also before any user code could call `mu.lock()` (whether directly or by using `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`).

Nonetheless, your use case is safe – in fact, `std::mutex` initialization is even more safe than suggested by the previous answer.

The reason for this is that any variable with static storage duration (✓ check) that is initialized with a constant expression (where a call to a `constexpr` constructor is explicitly considered as such – ✓ check), is *constant initialized*, which is a subset of *static initialized*. All static initialization happens strictly before all dynamic initialization, and hence before your function can be called the first time. ([basic.start.static/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.static#2))

This applies to `std::mutex` because `std::mutex` has only one viable constructor, the default constructor, and it is specified to be `constexpr`. ([thread.mutex.class](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/thread.mutex.class))

Therefore, in addition to the usual atomicity guarantee that C++11 and higher makes for *dynamic initialization* of static variables at function scope, other `std::mutex` instances with static storage are also completely unaffected by initialization order issues, e.g.:

```
 #include <mutex>

 extern std::mutex mtx;
 unsigned counter = 0u;
 const auto count = []{ std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mtx}; return ++counter; };
 const auto x = count(), y = count();
 std::mutex mtx;
```

If `mtx` was dynamically initialized, this code would exhibit undefined behavior, because, then, `mtx`'s initializer would run after that of the dynamically initialized `x` and `y`, and `mtx` would therefore be used before it is initialized.

(In pthread, or common implementations of `<thread>` that use pthread, this effect is achieved by the use of the constant expression `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.)

PS: This is also true for instances of `std::atomic<T>`, as long as the argument passed to the constructor is a constant expression. This means e.g. that you can easily make a spin lock based on `std::atomic<IntT>` that is immune to initialization order issues. `std::once_flag` has the same desirable property. A `std::atomic_flag` with static storage duration can also be statically initialized in either of two ways:

- `std::atomic_flag f;`, is zero-initialized (because of static storage duration and because it has a trivial default c'tor). Note that the state of the flag is nonetheless unspecified, which makes this approach rather useless.
- `std::atomic_flag f = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;` is constant initialized and unset.  This is what you'd actually want to use.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is fine. The first time the function is called `mu` will be initialized (and this is guaranteed to be thread safe and only happen once) and then `guard` will lock it.  If another thread calls foo it will wait at

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mu);
```

until the first call to `foo` completes and `guard` is destroyed unlocking `mu`.